# Как обработать запрос вызванный из html файла при помощи Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Код "сервера", если конечно можно так выразиться...

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Подключаю вёрстку, я не знаю других методов поэтому пользуюсь этим
html = ""
with open('verstka.html', 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index(text1, text2):
# Хочу дозаписать в файл данные полученные из формы
    with open('somefile', 'a') as f:
        string = text1 + ': ' + text2 
        f.write(string)

    return html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

содержимое самого файла с вёрсткой

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="text" name="text2">
        <button type="submit">Нажми на меня</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда запускаю в командной строке всё работает нормально, но стоит мне зайти на сам сайт, то получаю вот это:

```
    [2020-12-13 14:00:08,590] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "D:\Python\Python391\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    TypeError: index() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'text1' and 'text2'
    127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2020 14:00:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Я так понял что ошибка в том что он не видит аргументы text1 и text2, вообще без понятия как это по другому сделать, помогите пожалуйста, буквально час назад Flask сел изучать...

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы почитали про Flask, потому как есть `render_template()` А то, что вы привели в качестве примера - это далеко не Flask.

Comment: так же советую прочесть про модуль `request` который есть в `flask`

Comment: А еще лучше изучите вот это - [Мега  Учебник по Flask](https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`q1218064.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html'), 200


@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    print('form text1', request.form['text1'])
    print('form text2', request.form['text2'])
    
    with open('blabla.txt', 'a') as f:
        string = request.form['text1'] + ': ' + request.form['text2']
        f.write(string)
        f.close()
    return 'ok', 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='10.10.10.2', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Добавьте обработчик для отправленных данных, которые находятся в `request.form` под тем же ключом, что и ввод `name`.

`templates/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="text" name="text2">
        <button type="submit">Нажми на меня</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- `action`: URL-адрес, на который отправляются данные формы при отправке. Создайте его с помощью `url_for`. Его можно не указывать, если тот же URL обрабатывает форму и обрабатывает данные
- `method="post"`: Отправляет данные как данные формы с помощью метода POST. Если не указан или явно установлен get, данные передаются в строке запроса ( `request.args`) с помощью метода GET
- `enctype="multipart/form-data"`: Когда форма содержит входные данные файла, она должна иметь эту кодировку, иначе файлы не будут выгружены и Flask их не увидит
- для `input`нужен параметр `name`